# Replace '#' for %23 in tweet button

Tags: html, twitter, blogger

My blog has the tweet button that works normally like any other: it gets the page's title and URL through data:post.title/data:post.url respectively. The trouble is that some days ago, I added a hash and the number of the post in their titles. For example, the title of the 129th text was "Kernel" and then I've renamed to "#129 Kernel" (without the quotes) and after this, the tweet button does not read the # which is in post's title and anything that comes after it.

I've realized that if I replace the # for %23 it works perfectly, but is there any way to do this replacement automatically, without rename all of the posts and take out the # of them?

Post's link: http://einconformado.blogspot.com/2015/06/kernel.html

Comment: Is the Twitter link something that you have coded yourself? Or is this something provided by blogspot?

Comment: It's something manual, Squeakasaur. It came in the template and I edited by myself. I won't be able to copy it here now (I'm on mobile and the source is in my laptop), but it is something like that: <a expr:href="'http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Read' + data:post.title + in + data:post.url">Send to Twitter</a>

Comment: Do readers need to see the link you have provided in order to answer the question? If so, the question is off-topic as it stands, since it is important that everything one would need to answer the question is added to the post itself. This is to make it easier for readers, and to protect against broken links.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following data tag instead -

```
expr:href='&quot;https://www.blogger.com/share-post.g?blogID=&quot; + data:blog.blogId + &quot;&amp;postID=&quot; + data:post.id + &quot;&amp;target=twitter&quot;'
```

This is the native sharing URL generator provided by Blogger. This will generate the URL of the form -

```
https://www.blogger.com/share-post.g?blogID=BLOGID&postID=POSTID&target=twitter
```

This will then automatically redirect to Twitter sharing window with the Title and URL of the post auto-filled. The title of the post will be escaped. This sharing URL generator can also be used for generating sharing URLs for other social networks as well (aka `facebook`,`pinterest`,`email` by replacing the `target` parameter in the first line)

The downside of this being that you can't add users to follow or add hashtags like you would normally be able to do when building the Twitter sharing URL.

Comment: Hello, Prayag. I've tried this option, but it didn't work yet. It works if post's title does not contain the '#', but if it contains the hash, the URL is not read (it just shows the '&target=twitter' in the end of the link). I am really thinking about to take out the # of all of the posts, although I really think that there is a way to solve this without edit every post's title. I thank you, man! God bless you! =]

Comment: @Vítor This code should work without any problem. Here is a GIF demonstrating the process of integrating this into your blog as well as it working with special characters in the title - http://i.imgur.com/P3ldL1d.gif

Comment: Yes, Prayag, it should. I've probably done something wrong... but I have already taken out the '#' of every post's title and, obviously, the tweet button works. Even though, I thank you a lot for the kindness. God bless you, man. Hugs! =]